# How to add dictionary items to jsonarray while in loop?

Tags: python, json, loops, in-place

So I have a data structure like so...a dictionary...

```
         fbIds = ["him", "her", "it", "that"]
```

then I have a database i'm adding a json structure to...

```
         res =  r.table("usa_nyc_bronx_merchants").insert({

                "street_address": streetName.lower(),
                "city": cityName.lower(),
                "state": stateName.lower(),
                "zipcode": zipcodeNumber.lower(),
                "county": countyName.lower(),
                "fbIds": [ADD DICTIONARY ITEMS TO THIS ARRAY]
          .....
```

How do i add the items in that dictionary into that that json array...mind you
all this code is already in a for loop.

Thanks!

Comment: `fbIds` is already an array, so this seems like it should be simple... if would help if you included the for loop in the example above as well so we could get a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fbIds` is already an array (`list` in python terms). So you should be able to just do:

```
res =  r.table("usa_nyc_bronx_merchants").insert({
            "street_address": streetName.lower(),
            "city": cityName.lower(),
            "state": stateName.lower(),
            "zipcode": zipcodeNumber.lower(),
            "county": countyName.lower(),
            "fbIds": fbIds
      .....
```

Comment: Easy money. Trying to over think it for no reason.

Comment: Haha happens to the best of us :)

Comment: @sirvon please mark as answered if this helped you solve your problem!